# Clear all children subcategories of a selected (sub)category in a chained dependent dropdown combobox selection

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to implement chained dependent dropdown combobox selection, so you start with one combobox for main category and once you select main category, another `<select>` appears for selecting a subcategory, and so on until the innermost (most specific) subcategory is selected.

Let's say that I have two main categories, Books and Shoes, so if I go Books -> Textbooks -> Primary school, then I decide to go for Shoes instead, four `<selects>`s would appear. Instead, I want to clear all children subcategories of a selected (sub)category (in this scenario, two `<select>`s (Textbooks and Primary school)) and leave the user to chose from only main category. Or, if I chose Books -> Literature, it should remove the Primary school/High school `<select>` and show subcategories of 'Literature'.

Here is my jQuery code in a Django template:

```
{% extends 'pages/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Create a product</h1>
<form method='POST' id='productForm' data-products-url="{% url 'products:ajax_load_categories' %}">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $r_ = function() {
        var url = $("#productForm").attr("data-products-url");
        var categoryId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({                       
          url: url,                    
          data: {
            'category': categoryId
          },
          success: function (data) {
            if (data != 'leaf_node') {
              $("#productForm").append(data);
            }
            $('select').change($r_);
          }
        });

    } //end of $r_
    $('select').change($r_);
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

...and here is my view:

```
def load_categories(request):
    category_id = request.GET.get('category')
    subcategories = Category.objects.get(id=category_id).get_children()
    if subcategories:
        return render(request, 'products/category_dropdown_list_options.html', {'subcategories': subcategories})
    return HttpResponse('leaf_node')
```

`products/category_dropdown_list_options.html`

```
<select>
    <option value="">---------</option>
    {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
        <option value="{{ subcategory.pk }}">{{ subcategory.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

This currently works like this, whenever a value is changed in a combobox, an AJAX request is fired which calls a view that renders another `<select>` if a category has children, otherwise returns an HttpResponse which stops attaching the listener.

I am using `django-mptt` to model my categories:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class Category(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('parent', 'slug',))
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I overcome the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `$(this)` to get access to the current `<select>` which I used for selecting the next `<select>`s and removing them, before appending new ones. They all have to be sibling elements in order for this to work:

```
$(this).nextAll('select').remove()
```

So, to access that from inside the AJAX success, I had to store it in a variable and use that variable inside the callback.

I also changed `$('select').change($r_)` to use event delegation instead, because the way I had been doing it would call my function multiple times for each change. So, I changed that to:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', $r_);
```

and removed the .change() call inside the success callback.

This is the working code:

```
{% extends 'pages/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Create a product</h1>
<form method='POST' id='productForm' data-products-url="{% url 'products:ajax_load_categories' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Title</label>
    {{ form.title }}
    <label>Description</label>
    {{ form.description }}
    <label>Price</label>
    {{ form.price }}
    <label>Year</label>
    {{ form.year }}
    <label>Category</label>
    {{ form.category }}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $r_ = function() {
        var url = $("#productForm").attr("data-products-url");
        var categoryId = $(this).val();
        var toRemove = $(this).nextAll('select');
        $.ajax({                       
          url: url,                    
          data: {
            'category': categoryId
          },
          success: function (data) {
            if (data != 'leaf_node') {
              toRemove.remove();
              console.log(toRemove);
              $("#productForm").append(data);
            }
            else {
              toRemove.remove();
            }
          }
        });

    } //end of $r_
    $(document).on('change', 'select', $r_);
</script>
{% endblock %}
```